# With the ngAnimate module, is there a way to config when ng-enter/ng-leave class is added to a directive?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

With angular 1.2, I'm trying to animate a ngView whose associated templates have custom directives inside (markdown directives).

My animation is the simple [CSS3 example given in the tutorial](http://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_12#animating-with-css-keyframe-animations).

I noticed some flickering when changing routes that seems to be due to the **ng-enter class being added 'to late'**, that is after the directives are processed. In other words, during the processing of the markdown, the output view is displayed without the ng-enter class and is visible.

Is there a way to change this behavior ?

Note : ngCloak and $routeProvider resolve property are used to prevent other form of flicker.

Comment: From what I can tell you're having this issue: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/4225 There is a suggested solution in there as well.

Comment: @Tasos This is indeed the same issue. [The workaround suggested by marko](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/4225#issuecomment-30990805) does solve the problem. Thanks !